# I m receiving error "'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." on Windows 10

Tags: maven

Kindly help with this issue:

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file."  .

I tried to delete environment variables and path variable created and restart the system and recreate and ran `mvn -version` ... still the same error .

Comment: Enhancing the PATH variable in Windows with the appropriate location where to find `mvn` (bin directory of the distribution) afterwards close the Console and reopen it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart pc, after setting up your M2_HOME (pointing to your Maven-based dir, NOT the bin dir) and PATH (PATH=%M2_HOME%\bin;%PATH%)

```
dir %M2_HOME%\bin\mvn*
```

Right-click on My Computer >> Properties >> Advanced system settings >> System Properties window will get displayed Under Advanced >> Environment Variables

- Click on New to set Environment Variables

  Variable name: JAVA_HOME Variable value: C:\Program
  Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

  Variable name: M2 Variable value: %M2_HOME%\bin

  Variable name: M2_HOME Variable value: C:\Program Files\Apache
  Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.0

  Variable name: Path Variable value: %M2_HOME%\bin

Then click on Ok, ok, ok. Now restart your command prompt and check again with “MVN –version” to verify the MVN is running, you may restart your system also.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the above solution?   variable name: M2_HOME    VARIABLE VALUE: C:\SELENIUM\DMT-Build tool-MAVEN\apache-maven-3.8.6-bin\apache-maven-3.8.6     under SYSTEM VARIABLES.     And Path as  %M2_HOME%\bin

Comment: and do I have to set M2_HOME under the user variable also?

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully configured it after a long battle. Thank you!

```
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: C:\SELENIUM\DMT-Build tool-MAVEN\apache-maven-3.8.6-bin\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 1.8.0_202, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: No explanation as to what caused the problem or how you solved it. You should become a mystery novel writer!